# Set my function as Default

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have function and i want to create it as default

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[ModifiedBy]() 
RETURNS varchar(50) 
AS 
BEGIN 
    RETURN host_name() 
END
```

I want to do something like this, but it doesnt work. is it possible?

```
create default default_modifiedBy AS dbo.ModifiedBy()
```

Eror is `User-defined functions, partition functions, and column references are not allowed in expressions in this context.`

Comment: Can you order the code that you have tried and add it in the post? Question is not clear

Comment: What is default_modifiedBy ? You want to create a column in table, type or what?

Comment: its same like "Create default "abc" AS getdate()"

Comment: >>>This is function returning name of user who modified something<<< This function returns host_name() that has nothing to do with user and with modifications. It returns what your application passed as host_name with its connection string, and it can be everything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just tried doing this and it works fine for me:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ModifiedBy]()
RETURNS varchar(50) 
AS 
BEGIN 
    RETURN host_name() 
END 
GO


CREATE TABLE Test (
                     ID INT
                   , Hostname VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT ([dbo].[ModifiedBy]())
                 );
GO
```

**Test**

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Test ( ID )
VALUES  ( 1 )

SELECT * FROM  dbo.Test
```

Answer (score 1):

[From the MSDN page for `create default`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-default-transact-sql):

> Any constant, built-in function, or mathematical expression can be
> used, except those that contain alias data types. User-defined
> functions cannot be used

Like M.Ali writes, you can use a user-defined function if you create a column-bound default constraint with `alter table ... add constraint` or `create table ... (col1 default dbo.MyFunc());`.

For example, for [create table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#default):

> Only a constant value, such as a character string; **a scalar function
> (either a system, user-defined, or CLR function)**; or NULL can be
> used as a default

Comment: [From MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-default-transact-sql): Any constant, built-in function, or mathematical expression can be used, except those that contain alias data types. User-defined functions cannot be used

Comment: Ah, the restriction only applies to `create default`, not to defaults you apply directly to a database table.